# Can't test mui accordion with react testing library

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-testing-library

today I'm here because I'm having an issue with the Material UI Accordion and react testing library, when i try to run the render function over the accordion it responds with this message

```
  console.error
    Error: Uncaught [TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'appendChild')]
console.error
    The above error occurred in the <WithStyles(ForwardRef(Accordion))> component:
    
    Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
    Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.


TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'appendChild')
```

my render method is basically this:

```
    render(
      <Accordion>
        Hello, I'm content
      </Accordion>,
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the trailing comma might be the issue here, e.g.

```
    render(
      <Accordion>
        Hello, I'm content
-      </Accordion>,
+      </Accordion>
    );
```